# Golang types in net package

Tags: go

I'm coding in golang some tools to make my life easier and I'm not understanding at all how the types in the net package works. This is part of my code:

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
)


type configFile struct {
    gateway, net             net.IP
    mask, port               int
    telnetUser, telnetPasswd string
}

var dataConfig configFile

func createConfigFile() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)    
    fmt.Println("Let's fill te config file for the application.")
    fmt.Println("Which is your gateway IP?")
    readGateway, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    dataConfig.gateway = net.ParseIP(readGateway)

    if dataConfig.gateway == nil {
        log.Fatal("Problem here")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Your gateway is: ", dataConfig.gateway.String())
    }

}
```

My problem is the next:

I want to read an IP address from the command line and storage it in the configFile object, which I will user later to create a `.json` file with all the configuration of my program.

When I read from the command line the IP address the `readGateway` variable storages it ok, that's expected, but when I try to make
`dataConfig.gateway = net.ParseIP(readGateway)`
and I try to cast the string object to a `net.IP` object I'm always getting a `nill` in the `dataConfig.gateway` field, so I'm not able to work with that parameter neither convert it to a string.

Could somebody help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you pass the IP string to the program? Can you paste your main() func?

Comment: The main function have only a call to the `createConfigFile()`. I'm reading if from the standard input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`bufio.Reader.ReadString`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString)'s docs explain (emphasis mine)

> ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input,
>   returning a string containing the data **up to and including the
>   delimiter**

So `readGateway` ends up looking like `"192.168.1.1\n"`. Your newline delimiter would not exist in a properly formatted IP address, which means when you parse it with `net.ParseIP` it's kicking it out as `nil`.

You can use [`strings.TrimRight`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimRight) to trim out the newline:

```
readGateway, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
readGateway = strings.TrimRight(readGateway, "\n")
```

Comment: It seems to be that the TrimRight is not deleting the `/n` of the string.
*But* I've tried resizing the readGateway like `readGateway = readGateway[0:11]` and it's working now, so it's a big step. Thank you very much. I'm going to take a look at the docs of TrimRight to see what's happening.

Comment: so long as your gateway isn't 192.168.1.10 and its length should instead 13! ;). Best guess is that you've got `\r\n` ending the string, not `\n` (unix-style endings, not windows) but without you having done any sort of troubleshooting it's not really worth the effort to debug that for you. Good luck!

Comment: @DavidBarranco I rolled back your edit, since it doesn't clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of `net.ParseIP(s string)` states that if the string s provided is not a valid textual representation of an IP address the function will return a `nil` value, so that must be the case.

Please log the string s before calling `net.ParseIP` so you can check if you are passing and reading it properly in the program.